# Anatomically Correct Hypnotoad

Tags: internal-consistency, creature-design, evolution

All hail to the Hypnotoad!

[image: All hail to the Hypnotoad!]

I am interested in creating anatomically correct Hypnotoad, mainly known from the [Futurama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futurama) series.

While in Futurama the toad itself is pretty big, but I am actually interested just in having a toad which uses hypnotic abilities to catch its prey.

---

This is my addition to [Anatomically Correct Series](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2797/anatomically-correct-series/2798#2798).

Comment: I assume the allucinogenic toad we already have is not enough, right?

Comment: No time to answer right now, but there is a phenomenon of flies flying in predictable patterns underneath reflective objects. I’ve seen many houseflies tracing out squares and triangles underneath light fittings. Perhaps a toad could exploit that behaviour somehow...

Comment: Just make it the same as an actual real toad species of your choice.

Comment: @Mathaddict, answers are supposed to be more detailed than a one liner like yours. You are welcome to answer according to the expected standards.

Comment: @l.dutch if there is duplicate question, please mark it. I tried to search but came empty

Comment: No duplicate as far as I know. Just having read of somebody who used to lick a toad skin mucus to get high.

Comment: I WANT ONE.....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer lies in cuttlefish. By changing the color intensity of melanin particles in their skin, they can create hypnotic patterns that serve to calm their prey and lure them towards the cuttlefish's jaws.

Interestingly, there already exist frog species that can change their skin pigment, so it may not be too big a stretch to assume that they could adapt to produce hypnotic signals through change in skin color. Sadly I don't know of any frogs that can do it with only their eyes, like hypnotoad :(